# Attribute parameter from <action> element - equivalent in Struts 2

Tags: struts2, migration, struts1

In Struts1 you can use the attribute **parameter** from    element(struts-config.xml) and access it's value within the action class via the `actionMapping.getParameter()` method. For actions requiring multiple steps, the parameter is often used to indicate which step the mapping is associated
with.

Ex:

```xml
<action path="\something\Step1"
type="actions.SomethingAction"
parameter="step1"> ...

<action path="\something\Step2"
type="actions.SomethingAction"
parameter="step2"> ...
```

Which is the alternative solution for Struts2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters in the action configuration could be used instead

```xml
<package name="something" namespace="/something" extends="struts-default">
  <action name="Step1" class="actions.SomethingAction">
    <param name="step1" ...
  </action>
  <action name="Step2" class="actions.SomethingAction">
    <param name="step2" ...
  </action>
</package>
```

Comment: Can you help me with an equivalent method for actionMapping.getParameter () ?

Comment: Read docs [How do we access static parameters from an Action](http://struts.apache.org/docs/how-do-we-access-static-parameters-from-an-action.html).

Comment: I'm new on stackoverflow and I don't know how to do that?